# Geoserver GetCapabilities Takes Too Long

Tags: getcapabilities, geoserver-cloud

I have about 12 vector layers in a GeoServer instance (version 2.21-CLOUD) and when the client makes a WFS GetCapabilites request, it takes about 1 minute to receive the response.

The layer data is stored in a PostGIS database under RDS Instance via JDBCConfig. Is there any chance to improve the performance?

Interestingly WMS GetCapabilites is much quicker.

Comment: GeoServer cloud is still experimental, I believe it's being used in production capacity in a couple of production sites only. Can you test the same configuration with a vanilla GeoServer and see if you get the same issues?

Comment: Will give it a try with Vanilla Geoserver.  Thank you @AndreaAime.